# Will deleting my question also remove the reputation awarded to answerers?

Tags: support, reputation, closed-questions

One of my questions got closed, as it was very similar to some other posted questions (though I don't feel the linked questions answered what I was *trying* to ask).

There's no point to the question staying online, as it doesn't answer anything, so I was going to delete it - but if I do that will it remove the reputation of the helpful answerers I want to upvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sachin's answer was correct at the time he posted it, but it's no longer completely accurate. As of [March 2012](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/),

> [If] you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. "Worthwhile" here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater, and
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

Answer (score 2):

If you have obtained the reputation for that question or some other users have obtained reputation for your question, then yours/theirs reputation will be lost during the next recalc process. This result is not immediately visible on your profile, but sometime in future you will see a reputation drop.

In your case, the question or the answers have no upvotes or downvotes. Hence this will not affect anything if you delete the question. Only the effort/time spent by users on your question is wasted thats all.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.