# Will deleting a question remove reputation (clarification)?

Tags: support, reputation

Per this answered question from 5 years ago,

[Will deleting my question also remove the reputation awarded to answerers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77899/will-deleting-my-question-also-remove-the-reputation-awarded-to-answerers)

I see that reputation will be retained for answers that

1) Have a score of 3 or greater
**and/or**
2) have had exposure for 60 days.

In order for reputation to be retained for an answer to a deleted question, do BOTH conditions have to be fulfilled, or either?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's both conditions.

The post has to have a score of 3+ **and** be 60 days or older.